# JavaScript Print() Style Inconsistency

Tags: javascript, browser, printing, html

Edit:

Any recommended hacks?

I'm currently considering generating an image on the backend, then open that in a new window, then printing off the image.

---

I'm printing parts of a page by hiding other elements via

```
$(...).hide();
```

and then calling print via

```
window.print();
```

But in all browsers I encounter some style inconsistency. Specifically, background-color disappears.

Regular webpage view:

[image]

Print preview:

[image]

The relevant html (jade) are as follows:

```
amount-due.span2
  dl
    dt Amount Due
    dd.align-right <%= RP.util.currency_to_symbol[invoice.currency.toLowerCase()] %>
      <% if (invoice.state !== "paid") { %>
      span <%= invoice.total_amount %>
      <% } else { %>
      span 0
      <% } %>
```

and

```
d.darken <%= RP.util.currency_to_symbol[invoice.currency.toLowerCase()] %><%= invoice.total_amount %>
```

The relevant CSS are as follows:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Some browsers have a print setting that removes any `background` styles to save on ink usage. It has to be changed manually by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any browser that doesn't, for the sake of saving ink/toner, turn background colours and images off for printing.

Some provide a user preference to reenable it.

Design your stylesheet on the assumption that all your backgrounds will be white, and use some other means (such as bold text) to highlight particular bits of content.

Comment: Argh, is there a way around this, or maybe i should just create an image on the backend then print that?

Comment: i'm sure the product manager and graphic designer both really want the color and background-color

Comment: If precision printing is required, use a PDF. Browsers are designed with the assumption that that goal of printing is to produce something clear and readable, not a specific graphic design.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your browser doesn't print backgrounds.

If you you use Firefox, you can do:

File > Page Setup... > Format & Options > Options > Print Background (colors & images)

or

Firefox Button > Print... > Page Setup... > Format & Options > Options > Print Background (colors & images)

Comment: Well since it's my users that are doing the printing...i think it's not acceptable for me to tell them do all that...